# Get Position Of Field In Struct

Tags: c, struct

A fairly simple question (I hope).  Given a struct in C (the layout of which is known at compile time), is there a way (via macro, or other) that I can access the byte position of a named field in the struct?

Support for unions would be a bonus.  The compiler is VC++ 2008. Assume that `#pragma pack(1)` is used.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `offsetof`.  It should be in `stddef.h`, but in case you don't have that, a sample implementation (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof)):

```
#define offsetof(st, m) \
    ((size_t) ( (char *)&((st *)(0))->m - (char *)0 ))
```

For a union, the offset of every field is `0`.

Comment: Accepted, however I had to add a custom offsetofunion macro, because the one you provided would not support a union.  I just put union in front of the `st *` and it worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `offsetof`, from `<stddef.h>`.

(Unless MSVC++ 2008 doesn't provide it, in which case implement your own as per Carl Norum. I'm pretty sure it's been in since C89, though).